# hide a dismissible alert in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alert, aurelia

Can I tell a dismissable alert to only hide, not remove itself from the dom when dismissed?

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert" if.bind="message">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> ${message}
</div>
```

The problem is I'm not using jQuery for anything now-a-days. I need aurelia to just show/hide it based on the flag or existance of a `message`.

It works once, but as soon as I dismiss it, then it is removed from the DOM so new messages don't appear after that.

Comment: Instead of if.bind you could use a toggle class something like `${dismissed?:'hidden':''}`

Answer (score 4):

Besides the if.bind, there's also a `show.bind` ([manual](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#show)) or you can bind to the default hidden attribute using `hidden.bind`.

Like Matt stated, you can also use string interpolation to add a CSS class manually `${!message ? 'hidden': ''}`

Comment: I think that show.bind is what @demo is looking for in this instance, since it just set's the element to `display: none;` but keeps it in the dom.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a better way :) I'm my case I'm not using hidden but another class so I add some transitions in there.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do it like this...

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade-in ${dismissed ? 'hidden': ''}" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" click.delegate="dismiss" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> ${message}
</div>
```

And in the js

```
dismiss() {
    this.dismissed = this.dismissed? true: false;
}
```

If there's a cleaner way to do it I'd love to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

For my flash-container that display response message from ajax calls I set up a listener to the `close.bs.alert` event and adds deleted HTML to the DOM again.

```
$("#flash-container").on("close.bs.alert","#flash-alert",
/* The container that will hold the #flash-alert. 
 * This setup is neccessary so that the event will be caught
 * when the HTML is added once again.
 */
    function (e) {      
        var $alert = $(this).addClass("d-none");
        /* Remove the existing text */
        $alert.find("#flash-container-text").empty();
        /* e.delegateTarget will be #flash-container */
        e.delegateTarget.innerHTML = $alert[0].outerHTML;       
});
```